# Please give me an example of IMacros macros to visit all site entirely

Tags: web-crawler, imacros

So I give the first page and macros must visit all pages of this site.  (open a new tab for example of each page)

This one I found in the net, but this macros visit only links in one starting page, and not visit the second level in deep.

Thank you for the help!

```js
//imacros-js:showsteps no

//Testing forum post http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=7537&sid=2103c60e70f9c7051dcda5264874a488
//Idea is to read something in common on the page and open each link in a new tab.
var macro, retcode, url="", pos=1, stop=false;
while(!stop)
{
   macro="CODE:";
   macro+="TAB T=1\n";
   //macro+="TAG POS="+pos+" TYPE=A EXTRACT=HREF\n";
   macro+="TAG POS="+pos+" TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF\n";
   //ATTR=CLASS:*topictitle* 
   retcode = iimPlay(macro);

   if (retcode < 0)               // an error has occured
   {
      errtext = iimGetLastError();
      alert("1st Error "+retcode+": "+errtext);
      stop=true;
   }

   //Stop if extract found nothing or counter is too high as a precaution
   if((url = iimGetLastExtract()) == "#EANF#" || pos > 10000)
   {
      stop=true;
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      macro="CODE:";
      macro+="SET !TIMEOUT 15\n";
      macro+="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\n";
      macro+="TAB T=1\n";
      macro+="TAB NEW OPEN\n";
      macro+="TAB T="+new Number(pos+1)+"\n";
      macro+="URL GOTO="+url+"\n";
      macro+="TAB T=1\n";

      retcode = iimPlay(macro);

      if (retcode < 0)               // an error has occured
      {
         errtext = iimGetLastError();
         alert("2nd Error "+retcode+": "+errtext);
         stop=true;
      }
      pos++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code basically finds all the links on the page. Then it extracts the href, and constructs a new macro in the variable macro. Wich it then runs with the last command `retcode = iimPlay(macro)`
What you want is a recursive function, which not only opens a new tab for the href its finds but also runs the same function on the page its points to.
So you should make the above code into a function which accepts a URL as a parameter. And then when imacros finds and link, call the function with the links href.